# WSO2 Identity Server SAML2 SSO from external service with SAMLResponse

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 IS 5.0 as our IDP with OAuth2 authentication protocol for our Services. We have requirement where the external services wants to access our services by posting SAMLResponse for authentication.

The question here is, does WSO2 IS has inbuilt ACS that can be used for this SSO or we have to add ACS endpoint within our services and authenticate through  /token endpoint with SAML Assertion?

Answer (score 0):

IS has an inbuilt assertion consumer URL (https://localhost:9443/acs) which is used for the purpose of logging into the Management console using SAMLSSO.

If you want to allow an application to do Single Sign On using IS as IDP you need to define your own assertion consumer URL and register it when creating a service provider in IS.

I would recommend you to take a look at the travelocity sample[1] that exactly demonstrates your use case.

So you basically when someone wants to login to your app, you redirect them to IS and ask them to authenticate. IS will send a SAML Response upon successful authentication to your assertion consumer URL. There you can verify the response and allow the user to consume your service.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0